# Unit testing with XamDataGrid and Sorting event

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I'm trying to unit test a class, and that class uses a **XamDataGrid**.

My problem is that my code should trigger a **Sorted** or **Sorting** event from the XamDataGrid, but it doesn't: what am I missing?

Here how I create the grid:

```
public static class XamDataGridObjectMother
{
    public static XamDataGrid CreateGrid(params string[] columns)
    {
        var grid = new XamDataGrid();

        var layout = new FieldLayout();
        grid.FieldLayouts.Add(layout);

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            var field = new Field(column, typeof(string), column+" Label");
            field.Column = i;
            field.Width = new FieldLength(100);
            field.Name = column;
            layout.Fields.Add(field);
            i++;
        }

        var data = new List<XamDataGridFakeItem>();
        data.Add(new XamDataGridFakeItem("P1", "A1"));
        data.Add(new XamDataGridFakeItem("P2", "A1"));
        data.Add(new XamDataGridFakeItem("P3", "A1"));
        data.Add(new XamDataGridFakeItem("P4", "A2"));
        data.Add(new XamDataGridFakeItem("P5", "A2"));
        data.Add(new XamDataGridFakeItem("P6", "A2"));

        foreach (var xamDataGridFakeItem in data)
        {
            grid.DataItems.Add(xamDataGridFakeItem);
        }

        return grid;
    }

    public class XamDataGridFakeItem
    {
        public XamDataGridFakeItem(string portfolio, string area)
        {
            Portfolio = portfolio;
            Area = area;
        }

        public string Portfolio { get; set; }

        public string Area { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the part of my unit test where I programmaticaly add a sorting to the grid, and where it should raise a Sorted/Sorting event (probably both):

```
 var sortDescription = new FieldSortDescription("Portfolio", ListSortDirection.Descending, false);

 _dataGrid.FieldLayouts[0].SortedFields.Add(sortDescription); // That should trigger the event(s)!
```

Of course _dataGrid is initialised somewhere else with my object mother class showed above.

So my problem if it's not obvious already, is that me adding a sorted field *SHOULD* trigger a Sorted/Sorting event (it should sort the grid), but it doesn't, and I can't find any way to (programaticaly) force it to sort the grid and fire those events.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The [Sorting](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v12.2~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataPresenterBase~Sorting_EV.html) and [Sorted](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v12.2~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataPresenterBase~Sorted_EV.html) event are only fired in response to user interaction so it is expected that they do not fire when sorting the grid in code.

If you need to see what fields are sorted through the grid, you would check the relevant [FieldLayout.SortedFields](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v12.2~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.FieldLayout~SortedFields.html) collection to see what fields are sorted.

Note that if your test is to verify that sorting was successful, it may be better to check the order of the records in the grid rather than checking for the events to fire.